When build ffmpeg on windows with msvc and msys, occurs error LIBCMT.lib(loadcfg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __enclave_config
When build ffmpeg on windows with msvc and msys,
Error msgs occurs in msys terminal:
cl.exe is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

The error msgs in config.log are below:
link.exe -nologo -out:./ffconf.34uX3m9d/test.exe ./ffconf.34uX3m9d/test.o
LIBCMT.lib(loadcfg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __enclave_config
LIBCMT.lib(loadcfg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __guard_eh_cont_table
LIBCMT.lib(loadcfg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __guard_eh_cont_count
LIBCMT.lib(loadcfg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __volatile_metadata
./ffconf.34uX3m9d/test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 个无法解析的外部命令
C compiler test failed.

How to resolve my problem?
My configure options are below
./configure --toolchain=msvc --enable-pic --disable-doc --enable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-autodetect --target-os=win32 --enable-w32threads --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-dxva2 --enable-mediafoundation --disable-inline-asm --cc=cl.exe --host_cc=cl.exe --cxx=cl.exe --windres=rc.exe --ld=link.exe --ar='ar-lib lib.exe' --ranlib=':' --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-avcodec --enable-avdevice --enable-avformat --enable-avfilter --disable-postproc --enable-swresample --enable-swscale --disable-alsa --enable-amf --disable-libaom --disable-libass --disable-avisynth --disable-bzlib --disable-libdav1d --disable-libfdk-aac --disable-libfontconfig --disable-libfreetype --disable-libfribidi --disable-iconv --disable-libilbc --disable-lzma --disable-libmp3lame --disable-libmodplug --enable-cuda --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --disable-opencl --disable-opengl --disable-libopenh264 --disable-libopenjpeg --disable-libopenmpt --disable-openssl --enable-schannel --disable-libopus --disable-sdl2 --disable-libsnappy --disable-libsoxr --disable-libspeex --disable-libssh --disable-libtensorflow --disable-libtesseract --disable-libtheora --disable-libvorbis --disable-libvpx --disable-libwebp --disable-libx264 --disable-libx265 --disable-libxml2 --disable-zlib --disable-libsrt --enable-libmfx --enable-encoder=h264_qsv --enable-decoder=h264_qsv --enable-cross-compile --disable-static --enable-shared --extra-cflags='-DHAVE_UNISTD_H=0' --enable-optimizations --arch=x86_64 --enable-asm --enable-x86asm

